# how to convert Json value to List<String> in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is my API response, I want all building name to a string list

```
{
    "entity_id": "86",
    "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "location": "Al  Ttay",
    "image_field": "1595916594oad.jpeg"
},
{
    "entity_id": "87",
    "building_name": "Azmair",
    "location": " Eyal Nasser ",
    "image_field": "1596541099s.jpeg"
},

]
```

I tried this but not working

```
List<String> _buildlist = (jsonDecode(response['building_name']) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
print(_buildlist);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decode the JSON, then `map` each element to the relevant string, and re-form them into a list:

```
  var decoded = json.decode(j) as List;
  var names = decoded.map<String>((e) => e['building_name']).toList();
  print(names); // prints [Burj Khalifa, Azmair]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using the package 'dart:convert':

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  
  var json = '''[
    {
      "id":"67890",
      "name":"Hello World",
      "score" : 1000
    },
    {
      "id":"12345",
      "name":"Hello Sky",
      "score" : 2000
    }
  ]''';
  
  print('json is $json');
  var users = jsonDecode(json);
  assert(users is List);
  print('users is $users');
}
```

You can run the code in https://dartpad.dev/ and test it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get all the field's value in an array list. to do that first you need to parse all the responses. Create appropriate model class for any response use [app.quicktype.io](http://app.quicktype.io). here is the model class from app.quicktype.io,

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<ParseResponse> parseResponseFromJson(String str) => List<ParseResponse>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ParseResponse.fromJson(x)));

String parseResponseToJson(List<ParseResponse> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ParseResponse {
    ParseResponse({
        this.entityId,
        this.buildingName,
        this.location,
        this.imageField,
    });

    String entityId;
    String buildingName;
    String location;
    String imageField;

    factory ParseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ParseResponse(
        entityId: json["entity_id"],
        buildingName: json["building_name"],
        location: json["location"],
        imageField: json["image_field"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "entity_id": entityId,
        "building_name": buildingName,
        "location": location,
        "image_field": imageField,
    };
}
```

Now if you call  parseResponseFromJson(resonseString); then you'll have the list and you can go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first convert the JSON to a List of Maps<String,String> using json.decode(). Then iterate the List of Maps to create a new List of the building names. Remember to explicitly declare as many variables as possible and reduce the use of the 'var' keyword. It helps the compiler to compile the program faster and increases readability of code.

The code below shows my approach:

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  
 var response =[
    {
    "entity_id": "86",
    "building_name": "Burj Khalifa",
    "location": "Al  Ttay",
    "image_field": "1595916594oad.jpeg"
    },
    {
    "entity_id": "87",
    "building_name": "Azmair",
    "location": " Eyal Nasser ",
    "image_field": "1596541099s.jpeg"
    },
 ];
 List<String> _buildlist = List();
 List<Map<String,String>> data = json.decode(response);
 for(Map<String,String> i in data)
    _buildlist.add(i["building_name"]);

 print(_buildlist);
}
```